# How to plot circular sanky plot using R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I tried to plot the same plot as shown [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKwKt.png) using R. It displayed the results of thematic analysis (qualitative analysis), which tell the readers of open-end answers' themes.
I googled it using the key words "circular sankey diagram" but the [searched pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cius.png) were a little different from what i want. The origin nodes should be centered. I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Since I am not sure the exact name of this kind of diagrams, I have searched any possible answers via goolge and this forum but in vain.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.